# Dynamic Json Formation

Tags: java, json

I am reading one file through which I need to create a specific JSON structure to pass it on UI, but I am unable to write a code for JSON formation. So I created one Java class initialized my class, tried a lot but still now able to find a way, how to form it. Here is my main Java class where I am adding an element like this

```java
public class DynamicListForming {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeInfo cab = new NodeInfo("saurabh", "South");
        NodeInfo cab1 = new NodeInfo("South", "ZONE1");
        NodeInfo cab2 = new NodeInfo("ZONE1", "Street-1");
        NodeInfo cab3 = new NodeInfo("ZONE1", "Street-2");
        NodeInfo cab4 = new NodeInfo("ZONE1", "Street-3");
        NodeInfo cab5 = new NodeInfo("ZONE1", "Street-4");
        List<NodeInfo> NodeInfos = new LinkedList<NodeInfo>();
        NodeInfos.add(cab);
        NodeInfos.add(cab1);
        NodeInfos.add(cab2);
        NodeInfos.add(cab3);
        NodeInfos.add(cab4);
        NodeInfos.add(cab5);
    }
}
```

My NodeInfo class looks like this

```java
public class NodeInfo {
    private String nodeName;
    private String parentName;
    private List<NodeInfo> children;

    public NodeInfo(String parentName, String nodeName) {
        super();
        this.parentName = parentName;
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    public String getNodeName() {
        return nodeName;
    }

    public void setNodeName(String nodeName) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    public String getParentName() {
        return parentName;
    }

    public void setParentName(String parentName) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
    }

    public List<NodeInfo> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<NodeInfo> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

I need to form JSON structure like below

```json
"nodeInfo": {
  "name": "saurabh",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "SOUTH",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Zone-1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Street-1"
            },
            {
              "name": "Street-2"
            },
            {
              "name": "Street-3"
            },
            {
              "name": "Street-4"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestion on how to form this type of JSON structure, I struggled a lot and unable to find a way to dynamically create a list and object to form this structure.

Comment: I was able to create this structure by initializing list and object seeing the input, but file input might vary, so the code which I have written becomes irrelevant as it is unable to process any input

Comment: Can you try the gson library once.